# I'm getting an exception in just_audio Failed assertion 'initialIndex == null is not true. " when giving i number of audios to audiosource in player

Tags: flutter, just-audio

1.This is my code for playing "i" number of audios from phone. But when i do this code I'm getting an exception as " 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart': Failed assertion: line 3430 pos 12: 'initialIndex == null || indices.contains(initialIndex)': is not true. " . But when i gave hardcoded audios its working. Why..?

I didnt get my answer, just like i wrote before
await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(playlist.children[index]);
`when i did this the music played...`

`But i was able to make the shuffle with the code playlist.children.shuffle(); did the job`

`but the if i need to play music in a loop, its not working.` with hardcoded audios its working in a loop but if there are a number of audios i'm getting that same error..
await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(playlist,initialIndex: index);
giving the same error..

did this but nothing changes
audioPlayer.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);
await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(playlist,initialIndex: index);
error is the same.

Im not closing the question...

`The code i gave at first is this, audios are not playing...`

````
  ```
late ConcatenatingAudioSource playlist;

getPlaylistAutomatic() {
    for (var elem in songList) {
      playlist.children.add(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(elem.uri!)));
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
playlist=ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        useLazyPreparation: true,
        shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder( ),
        children: []);
getPlaylistAutomatic();
playerControllers.playSongconCat(songList[currentIndex].uri,playlist,index);
}

```

1.In the PlayerController class 

 ```

     playSongconCat(String? uri, ConcatenatingAudioSource playlist, int index) async {

     print(" Concateneting playlist -- ${playlist.children}");
        if(getPlayingStatus()!=true) {
          try {
            print("Play URI   $uri");
            await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(playlist);
            await audioPlayer.play();
            putPlayingStatus(true);
          }  catch (excep) {
            print("Error on Try Catch Concatenation WHile Playing${excep.toString()}");
        }
    }  

}
   ```

 I'm getting excaption as " 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart': Failed assertion: line 3430 pos 12: 'initialIndex == null || indices.contains(initialIndex)': is not true. "


3.But if I give hardcoded like 

        ```
        ConcatenatingAudioSource playlist=ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        useLazyPreparation: true,
        shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder( ),
         children: 
        [AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/10095")),
        AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/1000347089")),
        AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/483933")),
        AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/368491")),
        AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/368492")),
        AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/368493"))]);
        ```

4.it worked, but after playing 1 song app crashed, but it continued.. And there was no problem after.
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the phone storage media for playlist then initialize the list  with file path:

```
children: songList.map((filePath) {
            File audioFile = File(filePath);
            return AudioSource.uri(Uri.file(audioFile.path));
          }).toList()
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception...